# Sharing Data between Python and C++

Tags: python, c++, interface

I have an object in Python.
This object contains fields of data, 
that I want to pass to a c++ executable.

I have the source code of this executable.

When I run the executable I want the executable to get the data from my python object,
and do calculations with it.

Is this possible using python and C++?
If yes what is a good way to do it.

Comment: You could use the [Python API](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/) directly, or a 3rd party wrapper like [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/index.html), or look at any of the other results for searching "Python C++".

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) as a data interchange format. Protocol Buffers has built-in support for C++ and Python as standard and a few other languages have been supported by others if you required them.

Using Protocol Buffers you can define your object as a .proto message. You will want this object to contain all the data you require to be passed to your C++ code. You can sendthis data using any kind of stream (network/file) and can be read in by your C++ program (also using Procotol Buffers). Accessing the data is as easy as deserializing the stream.

**EDIT** You may be interested in [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) and [CapnProto](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/) which you could use to achieve similar results.

Hope this helps some.